# Weird result when animating line-height with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css

I have a table with four rows, whose line-height I want to animate with jQuery. I use the following code to shrink and hide the rows:

```
$("table tr").animate({ 'line-height': 'hide' }, 5000);
```

But instead of starting to shrink the rows from their current height, it first makes them really huge, and then starts shrinking. Press the Hide button in this fiddle to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/YzCzd/1/

It happens in Chrome and Firefox.

Is this a bug in jQuery, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps becuase `hide` is not a valid css property so it doesn't know how to animate that. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: It is indeed not a valid css value, but jQuery understands it (as well as `show` and `toggle`), see http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: After a bit of stepping through the jQuery code, I found the cause of the problem: jQuery considers line-height to be a number property (whatever it means, but eg. width and height are NOT number properties), and thus does not specify the unit when setting the value of the property. And it looks like a unitless value for line-height is taken as a value in `em` unit...

Comment: I found a workaround, but this is really hackish: force jQuery not to consider line-height as a number property. `$.cssNumber['lineHeight'] = false;`

Comment: Yes I just noticed that too... Well another solution would be to just use relative measurements for the line height instead. Unless you don't know the font size

Comment: You mean when specifying the initial line-height? Doesn't work either: it looks like jQuery takes the initial size in pixels (regardless of the unit you use in css), and sets it as the (unitless) value.

Comment: Seems like a worthy bug report then.

Comment: Done: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: the problem is that jQuery considers line-height to be a unitless number attribute, and thus sets its value without unit, which the browser interprets as `em`. See https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/164

A workaround is to force jQuery to consider line-height as a normal property:

```
$.cssNumber['lineHeight'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate will only work with attributes whose values can be **numbers**.

```
'line-height': 'hide'
```

Also I don't think `line-height` has the value called `hide`

**[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/YzCzd/2/)**

Comment: Actually `hide`, `show` and `toggle` are valid values for jQuery.animate, see http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: They are valid for `jQuery.animate`, not `line-height` css property.

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code with a list item. 
here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/CtGmH/1/

**CSS**

```
    #table {
    width: 100%;
}

#table ul {
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px;
}

#table ul.odd {
    background: red;
}
table li{position: relative; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="table">
    <ul class="odd"><li>A</li></ul>
    <ul><li>B</li></ul>
    <ul class="odd"><li>C</li></ul>
    <ul><li>E</li></ul>
</div>

<button onclick="window.show()">Show</button>
<button onclick="window.hide()">Hide</button>
```

**JS**

```
window.show = function() {
    $("ul").animate({ 'height': 30 }, 5000);
        $("ul li").css({'visibility':'visible'}).animate({ 'height': 30 }, 5000);
}

window.hide = function() {
    $("ul").animate({ 'height': 0 }, 5000);
    $("ul li").animate({ 'height': 0 }, 5000, function(){$("ul li").css({'visibility':'hidden'});});
}
```

Comment: You are working with the `height` property, which does indeed work. My problem is with the `line-height` property (because I need to use a table).